# Nested Json Arrays to nested HTML table using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multidimensional-array, templating

I'm trying to create a table report that pulls in records from a database and displays them in a table.
There are 2 types of records: products and components each pulled in using a get HTTP request.
The end result should be a series of interpolated tables along these lines (product on green background and it's related components on yellow):

```css
.product td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #b2ffa3;
  padding: 2px;
}
.component td {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  background: #fff1a3;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<table id="productsTable">
  <tr class="product">
    <td>Sed ut perspiciatis</td>
    <td>Sed ut perspiciatis</td>
    <td>Sed ut perspiciatis</td>
    <td>Sed ut perspiciatis</td>
    <td>Sed ut perspiciatis</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="nested">
    <td colspan="5">
      <!-- value of collspan equals number of columns in the parent table -->
      <table id="companentsTable">
        <tr class="component">
          <!-- the number of components will be different depending on the results of the db query -->
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="component">
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="component">
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<!-- The code is not strictly this but the result that the end user sees should be. -->
```

For simplicity and exemplification purposes, I have removed the first get.script call and commented out the second. I've manually created simplified json replicas of the JavaScript arrays that these calls return. Just to alleviate any doubt, the array qdb_data is the result of call 1 and respectively; fqdb_data -the results of call 2 for  each loop in the code below:

```js
//first query returns
qdb_data = [
    ["Product1Value1", "Product1Value2", "Product1Value3", "Product1Value4", "Product1Value5"],
    ["Product2Value1", "Product2Value2", "Product2Value3", "Product2Value4", "Product2Value5"],
    ["Product3Value1", "Product3Value2", "Product3Value3", "Product3Value4", "Product3Value5"]
];

// Second Query - loops trough components and returns related components for each product

fqdb_data =[
//First loop
["Component1Value1", "Component1Value2", "Component1Value3", "Component1Value4", "Component1Value5"],["Component2Value1", "Component2Value2", "Component2Value3", "Component2Value4", "Component2Value5"],["Component3Value1", "Component3Value2", "Component3Value3", "Component3Value4", "Component3Value5"],

//Second loop
["Component1Value1", "Component1Value2", "Component1Value3", "Component1Value4", "Component1Value5"], ["Component2Value1", "Component2Value2", "Component2Value3", "Component2Value4", "Component2Value5"],["Component3Value1", "Component3Value2", "Component3Value3", "Component3Value4", "Component3Value5"],

//Third loop
["Component1Value1", "Component1Value2", "Component1Value3", "Component1Value4", "Component1Value5"],["Component2Value1", "Component2Value2", "Component2Value3", "Component2Value4", "Component2Value5"]
];

//First db query brings in thew result above
$( document ).ready(function(){
 console.log(fqdb_data);
    var tmp = ""; 
    var ln = qdb_data.length;
    tmp +="<table id='productsTable'>\n";
    for(i=0;i<ln;i++){  // PROBLEM POINT
        tmp +="<tr class='product'>\n";
        for(var j in qdb_data[i]){
            tmp += "<td>"+qdb_data[i][j]+"</td>\n";
        }
        tmp += "</tr>\n";    
   
  for(k=0;k<ln;k++){
   var rid = qdb_data[k][3]; //store filter to group by in var "rid"
   
   //var url2 ="database.http.query.goes.here.FILTERED.BY.rid";    ***This would be necessary in a live scenario***
   //$.getScript(url2, function(){ ***pull in filtered data (fqdb)  from componnts table***
    
   for(l=0;l<fqdb_data.length; l++){
    
    tmp += "<tr class='component'>\n";

    for(var m in fqdb_data[l]){
      tmp+= "<td>"+fqdb_data[l][m]+"</td>\n";
    }
    
    tmp += "</tr>\n";
   }
  
  } 
 }
    tmp += "</table>\n";
    $( "div.wrapper" ).html(tmp);
});
```

```css
.product td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #b2ffa3;
    padding:2px;
}
.component td {
    border: 1px dotted red;
    background: #fff1a3;
    padding:2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

As you can see above, my problem starts at the comment "PROBLEM POINT" as I need the second get.script call to be inside this loop in order for the var "rid" that acts as my filter in the query to make sense and respect the relational nature of the db. (I did just quote myself just then- I must really be loosing it)
At the same time, having it inside the loop, creates copies for each component for as many times the loop runs, which I don't need.

This might just have the the simplest fix but it's just not obvious for a newbie like me so I will end with an apology for making you read this "short novel" :)

Please let me know if any further clarifications are required.

**TLDR: As you can see above, my problem starts at the comment "PROBLEM POINT" as I need the second get.script call to be inside this loop in order for the var "rid", that acts as my filter in the query, to make sense and respect the relational nature of the db.
At the same time, having it inside the loop, creates copies for each component for as many times the loop runs, which I don't need.**

Comment: Is there any reason you can't send all the data in one request and merge it all at server?

Comment: That's my thought as well. With your initial query, return a joined table of product and component info. As you're looping through the data, keep track of the product. When the product name/id changes, that's when you create a product row, then continue looping through to create the component rows. And so on. Every AJAX call requires overhead, even if you end up transferring more data in the first call (duplicate product info), you will still be better off than doing a bunch of AJAX calls.

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track! Managed to get it working doing a joint query on the server. Both replies appreciated.